How to create the new index based on aggregation in elasticsearch
 POST /_reindex?wait_for_completion=false //reindexing
    {
      "source": {
        "index": "as.event-154",
        "aggs": {
        "group": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ancestor_id",
            "size": 1 // note this
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_docs": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10,
                 "_source": false,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "event_id.keyword": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "bucketcount": {
          "stats_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "group._count"
          }
        }
      }
      },
       "dest": {
        "index": "as.event-154new1"
      }}

This is my elastic query to create the new index based on the aggregation filter. It creates a new index with all data. but I need only the specific conditions data. Please help to fix these issues

You can add query parameter in source.
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "test",
    "query": {...}, <---
    "aggs": {..}
  },
  "dest": {...}
}

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-select-query

it returns all the documents. I need the documents only to match the aggregated values.

I need to create the new indices based on aggregation result

Here from your message This is my elastic query to create the new index based on the aggregation filter. It creates a new index with all data. but I need only the specific conditions data. Please help to fix these issues.
The only things that I add is the query part. According to your comments I understand that the _reindex API call you shared is works fine. So, just add a query part and filter the data. Check the link in the comment for more info.

@balan did it worked?

No, it is not working
